# Body background image and jquery

Tags: wordpress, background, background-image, togglebutton

I am knew to **jquery** and I am having a bit of trouble with trying to get something working.

Basically I have a wordpress site, on each page is a different background image for the body tag. I want to be able to toggle on a button and then the body background image to drop about 500px.

Basically I have a hidden contact area on the top of my page, and when you click on the button(a.contact) the hidden contact area(#contactArea) is revealed by dropping down from the top, however when the contactArea drops some of my background image is hidden until you click on the button again.

What I am trying to achieve is that the background image drops (still completely visible) when the hidden contactArea is revealed, so that the background image is always visible.... I hope that makes sense?!

my css code is:

> body.page.page-id-240 {background:url(images/main-home-bg.jpg) center
>   600px no-repeat;

My current jquery is:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$("#contactArea").css('height', '0px');

$("a.contact").toggle( 
            function () { 
                $("#contactArea").animate({height: "225px"}, {queue:false, duration: 500, easing: 'linear'} )
            }, 
            function () { 
                $("#contactArea").animate({height: "0px"}, {queue:false, duration: 500, easing: 'linear'}) 
            } 
    ); 


});
```

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve this is to have your code which exposes the contacts area add an additional CSS class to the body tag e.g. `reposition-bg`. Then define the appropriate CSS class to modify the body's BG position. Does that make sense?

CSS:

```
body.reposition-bg {
    /*your new position for when contact area is exposed*/
    background-position-y: 200px 
}
```

and change your JS to:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$("#contactArea").css('height', '0px');

$("a.contact").toggle( 
            function () { 
                $("body").addClass("reposition-bg");
                $("#contactArea").animate({height: "225px"}, {queue:false, duration: 500, easing: 'linear'} )
            }, 
            function () { 
                $("#contactArea").animate({height: "0px"}, {queue:false, duration: 500, easing: 'linear'}) 
            } 
    ); 


});
```

Alternatively, if you have the flexibility to do so and it doesn't impede your UI, you could set the `#contactArea` to be `position: absolute` so it will be positioned *over* the top of your current content rather than pushing it down.

Comment: thanks for your help. - Im not sure, so are you suggesting have two classes for the body tag 1) body.page.page-id-240 {background:url(images/main-home-bg.jpg) center 600px no-repeat; and then 2)body.page-dropdown.page-id-240 {background:url(images/main-home-bg.jpg) center 900px no-repeat;

Comment: precisely that! It's always good to use CSS as a flag rather than setting styles inline as you keep a clean separation then. Your selectors look overly precise to me, i'd consider dropping the `.page` if it's superfluous. I've also expanded my answer to be more clear

Comment: Thats Great!! Thanks for your help, its appreciated

Comment: *ahem* Paul, you will find people will not answer your questions in future if you have a history of not accepting answers to your questions

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of this and once again thank you for your help